.net project with multiple solutions in azure devops
I have a .net 6 project with two solutions that i need in two Azure devops repositories.
I currently have everything in one repo.  However, i will need to have build and release pipelines for each of the solutions because their artifacts will be deployed to separate servers.
In the project folder, there are directories that are shared between the two solutions, like Lib and Packages.
If i were to break the project into two repos, where would i place the shared directories?
Or should i keep everything in one repo and try to build pipelines that can target each solution?

You can try to configure like as below:

Create 3 repositories (for example, repo1, repo2 and repo3):

The repo1 stores code files of the first solution.
The repo2 stores code files of the second solution.
The repo3 stores the shared files.



In the build pipelines (YAML pipelines) of repo1 and repo2, you can define repository resource to check out the shared files.
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: sharedFiles
    type: git
    name: repo3

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: sharedFiles

. . .

With above configuration, if you run the build pipeline of repo1:

The step "- checkout: self" will check out the files of repo1 into the directory "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/repo1" by default.
The step "- checkout: sharedFiles" will check out the files of repo3 into the directory "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/repo3" by default.
The "Build.SourcesDirectory" is a predefined variable for build pipelines. Its value is an absolute path on the agent machine where your source code files are downloaded by default.

Similar behaviors in the build pipeline of repo2.
For more details, you also can see the documentation "Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline".

EDIT:
On the checkout task, you also can use the path option to set the files are checked out into a different path.
For example,
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: sharedFiles
    type: git
    name: repo3

steps:
- checkout: self
  path: ./s

- checkout: sharedFiles
  path: ./s/packages

. . .

If you run the build pipeline of repo1 with the configuration like as above:

The files of repo1 will be checked out into the directory "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s".
The files of repo3 will be checked out into the directory "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/packages".
The "Pipeline.Workspace" also is a predefined variable for pipelines that its value also is an absolute path on the agent machine.
The value of "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s" point to same path as that of "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)". But you cannot directly use "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" to the path option as this option just receives the relative path to the root directory "$(Pipeline.Workspace)" by default.

Similar behaviors in the build pipeline of repo2.


Bright Ran i like the suggestion, one question: i will have to split up the files into 3 local directories then, to build the two solutions locally, will i have to edit the csproj and/or sln files to point to the shared directory? Or is there a better way to organize?

@jaykzoo, Yes, it is recommended to split the 3 parts into 3 repositories as I mentioned above. In each of your solutions, suppose you set the .csproj to reference the shared files from the 'packages' folder under the root of the solution, you can try the path option on the checkout task. See EDIT in my answer.
